# rn-apple-healthkit "unrecognised selector sent to instance"

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I am using the following project to my React Native project.

https://github.com/nutrisense/rn-apple-healthkit

I want to use the getWorkout function but can not solve the following error that is being thrown

[image]

This is where I call the getWorkout function. I think the error is with the permissions.

[image]

```
getWorkouts(){
  this.opt = {
    limit: 20,
    // activities: :["Soccer"],
    ascending: false,
    startDate: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    endDate: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    permissions: {
      read: ["Height", "Weight", "StepCount", "DateOfBirth", "BodyMassIndex", "ActiveEnergyBurned", "SleepAnalysis","HeartRate","BiologicalSex", "Workouts","MindfulSession"],
      write: ["Workouts"]
  }}
  AppleHealthKit.initHealthKit(this.opt: Object, (err: string, results: Object) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error initializing Healthkit: ", err);
        return;
    }
  AppleHealthKit.getWorkout(this.opt, async(err: Object, results: Array<Object>) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("err",err)
      return;
    }

    console.log(results)
  });
})}
```

Comment: Hello, please, add your code as a *code*, not as image. See it in [ask]

Comment: Apologies, I have added the code as code now.